# Expected a value of type 'SkDeletable', but got one of type 'Null' any solutions?

Tags: firebase, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Kcd.png)

Future uploadBannerImageToDb(url) async {
String downloadUrl = await storge.ref(url).getDownloadURL();

```
if (downloadUrl != null) {
  firestore.collection('slider').add({
    'image': downloadUrl,
  });
}
return downloadUrl;
```

}
/********************/

onPressed: () {
progressDialog.show();
_services
.uploadBannerImageToDb(_url)
.then((downloadUrl) {
if (downloadUrl != null) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
_services.showMyDialog(
title: 'New Banner Image',
message: 'Saved Banner Image Successfully',
context: context,
);
}
});
},